# Can Apache Hadoop HDFS help speed up the large file uploads (through a web browser) to a server?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As I understand, that Hadoop HDFS can't increase the network speed, but I was in a discussion with a few folks trying to brainstorm how we can significantly speed up our uploads, and someone said that they were able to significantly improve the upload speed using HDFS.

If a user is on a LAN (100 MBPS), is there someway Hadoop HDFS can help increase the upload speeds when the user uploads a large file >100GB using their browser?

Comment: Please dont edit your question away, especially when there already is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser and webserver will then become the bottleneck in itself. They must buffer the file on **that** server, and then upload to HDFS, as compared to a direct datanode writer of `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal`

HUE (which uses WebHDFS) operates in this fashion, and I don't think there is an easy way to stream that large of a file via HTTP to exist on HDFS unless you can do chunked uploads, and once you do, you'd then have multiple smaller files on HDFS rather than the original 100+ GB one (assuming you're not trying to append to the same file reference on HDFS)